# Database backup hangs both in SSMS and XMLA

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup, ssas

I am using SQL Server Analysis Services 2008 R2 Service Pack 3.  My database was recently upgraded from Analysis Services 2005 and since that time I have been unable to do a backup either from SSMS or by using XMLA - the process just hangs and says it's executing.   The backup should be very quick as the database is small (estimated size is 226mb).

I have to stop the service each time I try.

I've done a validate through BIDS and the database validates ok.

It is being run on a VM server with 8gb memory.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you doing your SSAS backups?  Could you show the code you use or describe your setup for SSAS backups? Are any errors being logged?

Comment: In SSMS, I've tried it with compression as well as without compression.   It just keeps 'executing'.   I've looked at a trace in SQL profile, and nothing shows there.   The only way to stop it is to restart the service.    I can see the backup file in the backup directory but it says 'corrupt' if I tried to restore from it so it's not usable.   I can query from the database and it validates in BIDS.   It processes without a problem so I feel the database is ok.